# Div hover pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `div2(height 20px vertical align centre)` inside `div1(100px)` and div2 having anchor tag.

On hover of `div1` I am showing hand pointer, but also want on click anywhere in `div1` area it should navigate to anchor tag url. Please refer  Image for more detail

```css
.test:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" style="height:100px">
  <div style=" position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">
    <a href="google.com" ; target="_blank" title="This link opens in a new window" style="color:#2e3940;text-decoration: initial;">Pawan Kotak</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual HTML and CSS, along with the code you wrote to attempt to solve this yourself, within the question

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>

.test:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="test"  style="height:100px"><div style="
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);" ><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="This link opens in a new window" style="color:#2e3940;text-decoration: initial;" > Pawan Kotak</a></div></div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have attached the code

Comment: Thanks. In future, please use the `edit` button in your question so the code can be formatted properly. I've done this for you in this case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with following way

```
$(div1).on("click",function(){
   window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
});
```

this is just a wayout.

Answer (score 4):

If the outer 'div' should behave like an anchor, just reorder the elements like this:

```
<a href="myAnchor.tld">
  <div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

You don't have to mess around with jQuery, if your markup could simply be structured the way it actualy works.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your div id's to be `div1` and `div2` here is a solution.

```
$('#div1').on('click',function(){
  $(this).find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

The script will attach a `click` event to the `div1` and when ever user clicks this div it finds the `a` tag with in it `$(this).find('a')` and triggers a click event on that anchor tag.

Comment: multiple times event get fired one for div and one for anchor tag when i click on anchor tag..how can i avoid multiple trigger of even

Comment: @pawankotak you can do `event.stopimmediatepropagation()` which will stop the bubbling of the events..

Answer (score 1):

you can also grow your anchor tag (there are several methods/approaches)

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
}
.test a {
  cursor: hand;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" style="height:100px">
  <div style=" position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">
    <a href="google.com" ; target="_blank" title="This link opens in a new window" style="color:#2e3940;text-decoration: initial;">Pawan Kotak</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but in my case some multi line text was also present in anchor tag which was creating problem. thanks